# Query $near using a value stored in the document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Having a problem filtering by a property that is in the documents I'm trying to return... Not even sure how to word the question. By example:

I'm making a system where a user will be alerted if a job pops up near them. That user is defined like:

```
var user = new Schema({
    location: {type:[Number], index: '2dsphere', required:true},
    maxDistance: {type:Number, required:true},
});
```

And the job:

```
var job = new Schema({
    location: {type:[Number], index: '2dsphere', required:true},
});
```

When a job is created, how do I find the the right users? I need the the .maxDistance property from the user...

```
var job = //new job, save, etc.

users.find({
    location: {$near: job.location, $maxDistance: ????user.maxDistance??? }
}, function(err, users){});
```

Is there a way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using the aggregation framework and it's own [**`$geoNear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) pipeline operator that "projects" a "distance" from the query results into the document itself:

```js
users.aggregate(
    [
        { "$geoNear": {
            "near": job.location,
            "spherical": true,
            "distanceField": "distance"
        }},
        { "$redact": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": { "$lt": [ "$distance", "$maxDistance" ] },
                "then": "$$KEEP",
                "else": "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,results) {
       // deal with response
    }
);
```

So the `$geoNear` essentially does the `$near` query but also returns the "mandatory" field inclusion of "distance" specified as whatever you want to call it from the "distanceField" parameter.

Then the [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) stage looks at the results and "logically compares" the value returned there to the value already present in your object to see if it is "less than" than value and therefore qualifies as within the criteria you are searching for.

This is a basic "two stage" aggregation pipeline to first "match" and then "filter" the results based on your criteria.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, and it works. Thanks!